# AutoLayout acts strangely when translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to false

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have my auto layout constraints set up like so:

[image]

With this line included:
`self.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`
The result looks like this:

[image]

With the line commented out, it looks like this, which is pretty much what I expect based on the constraints I've added.

[image]

Since it only works with the resizing mask constraints added, I can only assume that I am missing some vital constraints, but it seems like I have covered everything already? What could be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false only has bearing for how a view should be resized in respect to its superview since that's all autoresizing masks can affect. `UITabBarController` is managing adding and resizing of its viewController's views, you need not worry about autoresizing masks or constraints for the viewController's views.

Interface Builder will automatically set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to false for any view you have constraints relating a view to its superview. The only case when you will need to explicitly set this to false is if you are adding constraints in code for a view and don't want the auto-resizing masks to be converted, usually.

Comment: Ok so why does it have such a drastic effect on this view then? It is only that one line of code different between the two screenshots. Since I have set constraints in IB shouldn't it already be set to false and therefore make no difference?

Comment: The view itself won't have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to false because there are no constraints that relate it to its parent view.

Comment: It looks so different because without the autoresizingMask becoming constraints, the width of your view is being determined by its interior contents. The size you see in the messed up screen is the smallest width needed to satisfy all of the constraints internal to the view.

Comment: This answer is correct. I'd add that, if you're creating your views via the storyboard, you never need to touch the `translates...` property. That's only for views you've created in code that you want to size and position using constraints.

Comment: I still have a hard time wrapping my head around this but I think it's a bit clearer now. Thank you